# RoR: send additional data on for submit with Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm working on a rails form where I need to send an array created in Jquery to my rails controller.  I've had a hard time getting the data in the proper format.

I managed to get the Jquery array to send through AJAX when doing an update of this model.  It sends the normal PATCH and an additional PATCH for the array parameter.  So 2 updates.  Everything works find for updates, it's a bit hacky but does what I need it to.

This doesn't work on create though since I can't send two POST requests to create the same object?  Does that make sense?

So I guess my question is how can I get my AJAX data to tag along with the normal form submit?

Here's

```
    $('#employer_job_submit_button').on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"/jobs/<%= @job.id %>",
        type:'PATCH',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
          job: {
            benefits: tags_array
          }
        }
    });
  });
```

Here's my view (part of it)

```
<%= form_for @job, :html => {:class => 'profile_form'} do |f| %>
.....
<div>
    <%= f.submit "Post Job", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block", id: "employer_job_submit_button" %></div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

I tried separate code just for creating new jobs.  Like this:

```
$('#employer_job_submit_button').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var form_data = $('form').serialize()
      $.ajax({
        url:"/jobs",
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
          data:{
      job: form_data
    }
});
```

});

That sends all my form data through AJAX but I can't figure out how to add the "benefits" array to the form data.  Also this is not really what I want to do because it bypasses the standard Rails form.

I just want to add my Jquery created array along with the form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That sends all my form data through AJAX but I can't figure out how to add the "benefits" array to the form data.

You may simply add the stringified array version to your data.

From:

```
dataType:'json',
      data:{
        job: form_data
   }
```

To:

```
data: {
      job: form_data,
      benefits: JSON.stringify(tags_array)
}
```

In this way you will receive on your server two variables like in the following example:

```
job:firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse
benefits:["Saab","Volvo","BMW"]
```

Instead, if you want to continue to add to your serialized form data your array you can use  [jquery param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) like in the following:

```
var form_data = $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({"benefits": tags_array});
```

In this last way you need to decode the job parameter in your server side in order to extract the **benefits" array.